# Spark REST API is not running on port 4040

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark running in Standalone mode. I try to access the REST API. I tried to connect to localhost:4040 as documented. But, it fails with Connection Refused. Clearly nothing is running on that port.

But, I am able to get the the full listing from localhost:8080/json/. But, this includes everything. I am trying to get the status of a particular app-id.

What am I missing? How do I get the status of one app. Mainly, which port should I connect to access the REST API?

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api